# How to fix "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" for my code

Tags: node.js, promise

I was trying to write data into my .txt file.
but an unhandled promise exception occurred.

I already added err statement in `file.writeFileSyn` but it seems like useless at all.
How can I add promise part into the f`ile.writeFileSync`?

```
let file = fs
            .createWriteStream('depositeOrder.txt')
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('[Writing error] : ' + err);
            });

        for (let content of readResult.entries()) {
            file.writeFileSync(content[0] + '|' + content[1], err => {
                console.log('We have an writing error');
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
        file.end();
```

This is the error message that I got

> (node:21713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
>   file.writeFileSync is not a function
>       at getDeposite (/Users/jinwoopark/exkr-fds-service-2/apps/MonitorKrwDeposite.js:144:18)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) warning.js:18 (node:21713) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
>   an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
>   which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is to remember you're creating a file stream with the createWriteStream function. This does not have a writeFileSync method present.

Perhaps try this code:

```
let fileStream = fs
    .createWriteStream('depositeOrder.txt')
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.error('[Writing error] : ' + err);
    });

for (let content of readResult.entries()) {
    fileStream.write(content[0] + '|' + content[1] + '\n');
}

fileStream.end();
```